# Firebase endAt() method don't work with FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display all result, where field **"userGood"** ending with **"true"**.  I am use next code in FirebaseListAdapter.

```
FirebaseListAdapter<User> firebaseSuccessfulTaskListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<User>(
                this, User.class,
                R.layout.item_user,
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                      .child("users").orderByChild("userGood").endAt("true")){

      @Override
      protected void populateView(View v, Task model, int position) { }
};
```

Data structure:

```
{
    "users": {
        "1": {
            "name": "bob",
            "userGood": "bob_true"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "max",
            "userGood": "max_false"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "mike",
            "userGood": "mike_true"
        },
        "4": {
            "name": "bob",
            "userGood": "bob_false"
        }
      }  
     }
```

When i use this code, they *display to me all data* with my database. Can you help me how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endAt) is *endAt*, not *endWith*. You're getting everything that comes before "true" alphabetically. The Firebase API does not support partial text matching. Either look into a third-party text search solution like **ElasticSearch/[Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight)**, or refactor your data model so that your queries can be made using the built-in functions. For example, why can't `userGood` just be a Boolean `true` or `false`?